# can't add to one to many relationship in grails - hibernate lazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm working on a grails app that has a one to many relationship between User and Tasks. When I create a task, I either get an error:

Property [user] of class [class app.Task] cannot be null or
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: app.User.tasks, no session or session was closed

I am able to successfully save a task to the user in the bootstrap, but am unable to do so in the TaskController.

I'm pretty sure that I've got one line of code wrong and am wondering what it is. My code is below.

```
def save() {
    def taskInstance = new Task(params)
    println "attempting to save ${session.user.toString()}"

    println "adding task to user"
    def tasks = session.user.getTasks()
    println "got tasks"

    println "adding task to user"
    session.user.addToTasks(taskInstance) <--error here
    println "task added successfully"


    if (!taskInstance.save(flush:true)) {
        println "task saved and flushed"

        render (view: "create", model: [taskInstance: taskInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code:'default.created.message', 
        args: [message(code: 'task.label', default: "Task"), taskInstance.id])
    redirect(action:"show", id:taskInstance.id)
}
```

Comment: Actually, looking over your example controller code again, what's session.user? It it an actual instance of your user domain? That seems odd ... typically you would carry the user.id there not a bound instance.

Comment: the session.user is a User domain object, which I set when logging in. Is it better to change that to session.user = loggendInUser.id?

Answer (score 1):

Working directly with an object stored in the Http Session is generally not a good idea.  What I would do is the following:

```
def save() {
  def user = User.get(session.user.id)
  // or
  def user = session.user.merge() // not 100% this would work right

  ... all your other code

}
```

Reason is that the User is detached from the hibernate session and you need a hibernate session for all the persistence and GORM goodness to work correctly.

Comment: Not most likely, most definitely :)